# How to hide gray boxes where the scrollbar is in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have hidden the scrollbars in VSCode. Whenever I click on a block of code (if statement, for, function def, etc.) these little gray boxes show up where the scrollbar used to be. How can I hide them? Look at the two blocks on the far right side of the image below.[image]

Comment: if you want to make _everything_ in there transparent, then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59002585/11107541.

Answer (score 3):

The grey bars you're seeing on the right side indicate where the block of code begins and ends.  You can disable this with:

```
"editor.matchBrackets": false
```

Unfortunately this will also stop the highlighting of the opening/closing brackets in the code as well. To remove the highlighting in the overview ruler without also removing the highlighting in the editor, set the color of `editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground` to be transparent. Keep in mind that a reload is required for this particular color change to take effect.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground": "#00000000",
},
```

Additionally, you can remove the cursor's current location from the overview ruler with:

```
"editor.hideCursorInOverviewRuler": false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's worked for me recently.

```
"editorOverviewRuler.background": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.border": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.findMatchForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.rangeHighlightForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.selectionHighlightForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightStrongForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.modifiedForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.addedForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.deletedForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.errorForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.warningForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.infoForeground": "#000000",
"editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground": "#000000"
```

I used a solid black to go with my theme but of course you could choose another.

As someone else said, this feature is called the "overview ruler" and the color settings are described in [the docs' section called "editor colors.](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)"